# Are programming languages converted in machine code by compilers?

Tags: performance, compiler-construction

If so, why different programs written in different languages have different execution speeds?

Comment: Yeah, the computers can only understand binary all 0's and 1's.

Comment: programs are converted into machine code not programming languages.

Comment: maybe my question wasn't clear enough.. if every program is compiled in machine code, why then 2 same programs written in different languages have different execution speeds (if they are both, at the end, compiled in machine code)?

Comment: Because the quality and efficiency of the **compilers** can vastly differ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though programs written in different languages are converted into machine code at the end of the day, different languages have different implementation to say same thing.

You can take analogy from human languages e.g the English statement `I am coming home.` is translated to Chinese as `我未来的家。`, as you can see the Chinese one is more concise though it is not always true; same concept applies to programming languages.

So in the case of programming languages a machine code X can be written in programming language A as `2X-X`, programming language B as `X/2 + X/2`...but executing machine code `X` and `2X-X` will result same result though their performance wont same ( this is hypothetical example but hope it makes sense.)

**Basically it is not guaranteed that a program with same output written in different programming languages results in same machine code, but is converted into a machine code that gives same output, that where the difference comes.**

But [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40400/what-determines-the-speed-of-a-programming-language) will give you thorough info

Comment: my concern was about the fact that if "X" (machine code phrase) has the meaning of "i am coming home", and "我未来的家".. these 2 languages, even if they are more or less concise than the others, mean X anyways.. and so the machine should run X always at the same speed. I'll read the post you linked, thanks

Comment: No you dont have to go from X to `我未来的家`, when program is compiled it goes from  `我未来的家` to X.

Comment: yeah that was what i meant.. 我未来的家 goes to X, as "i am coming home" does

Comment: yeah great now check the example in my answer.

Comment: it's not really clearer.. because it makes sense that "2X-X" is equal to "X" but with more "steps" to get X for the first one.. but the computer is running X after the compiler had already calculated 2X-X, so the difference should have been eliminated.. anyway the link let me understood.. plus the fact that i hadn't counted the fact that different languages use different compilers with different quality

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: they don't produce the *same* machine code. They might produce different machine code which still produces the same side effects (same end result), but via different machine instructions.

Imagine you have two interpreters (let's say male and female just to distinguish them) to translate what you say into some other language. Both of them may translate what you say properly into the desired language, but they won't necessarily be equally efficient. One of them might feel the need to explain more of what you meant, one might be very terse and translate what you say in a very short and sweet way.

Performance doesn't just vary between languages. They vary between compilers for the same programming language.

For example, with C, the performance difference between GCC and Tiny-C can be about 2 to 3x, with Tiny-C being roughly 2-3 times slower.

And it's because even within the same programming language (C), GCC and Tiny-C don't produce identical machine instructions. In the case of Tiny-C, it was optimized to compile quickly, not to produce code that runs as quickly. For example, it doesn't make the best use of the fastest form of memory available to the machine (registers) and spills more data into the stack (which uses anything from L1 to DRAM depending on the access patterns). Because it doesn't bother to get so fancy with register allocation, Tiny-C can compile code quite quickly, but the resulting code isn't as efficient.

If you want a more in-depth answer, then you should study compiler design starting with the Dragon Book.

Answer (score 1):

Because 1) the compilers are written by different people so the machine code they generate is not the same, and 2) they make use of preexisting run-time libraries of routines to do math, input-output, memory management, and more, and those libraries are also not the same, for the same reason.

Some compilers do not generate machine code, because then the resulting code would not be portable to different machines, so instead they generate code for a fictitious general computer.
Then on any particular machine that code is either interpreted directly by an interpreter program, or it is translated into that machine's code, or a combination of these (look up just-in-time(JIT) compiler).